# Is it the same to say 'with neither' or 'without both' in context?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, paraphrasing

Is it the same to say 'with neither' or 'without both' or 'with miss' in this context? What part of speech is 'neither' here?

> He had, in short, all the Byronic ennui **with neither** of the Byronic
>   outlets: genius and adultery.

THE FRENCH LIEUTENANT’S WOMAN by John Fowles

Answer (score 1):

Neither is a conjunction meaning 'not one or the other of two'. 'Without both' would be clumsy ('without' alone would work), and 'with miss' doesn't mean anything in English.